# String topology in string theory

Tags: string-theory, topology, topological-field-theory, string-field-theory, algebraic-topology

How do string topology, string field theory and topological strings interact? Does anybody see a global picture? By string topology I mean the TQFT based on the homology of the space of loops described in https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4859